# How do you get the value of localstorage, without setting it as a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know that's probably very confusing, but what I want is to get the value of a localstorage, without setting it like:

```
var cookies = localStorage.totalCookies
```

I'd want it to be like this:

```
var cookies = value of localstorage.totalCookies
```

I want this so that the var cookies doesn't equal localstorage as I want a **one time** change to the var cookies, not a constant localstorage updating.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem

Comment: What did you save in `localStorage.totalCookies`?

Comment: Just curious, but unless we're talking about actual cookies, preferably chocolate chip, why are you storing or reading cookie data in/from `localStorage` rather than using cookies?

Comment: This appears to work out of the box, which I would expect since you're getting a string value and not an object reference. See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/umvbs1aL/2/). Can you post an example of when this doesn't occur?

Comment: @War10ck It's a cookie clicker clone.

Comment: @trincot The amount of cookies someone has saved locally.

Comment: That is crucial information to understand your problem. Maybe you could edit your question, and add that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data type of what is stored in `localStorage` is always `string`, even if you wrote a numerical value to it.

To get back the numerical value, you just need to coerce it back to a number, for instance with the unitary `+`. You should also provide a default value for when the entry is not present in `localStorage`. If that default value is 0, then you can write it like this:

```
var cookies = +localStorage.totalCookies || 0;
```

Or, if you want to test for the presence of that entry, and do another test on whether it is numerical:

```
if (localStorage.totalCookies === undefined) {
    console.log('The totalCookies entry was not found');
    // etc..
} else {
    var cookies = +localStorage.totalCookies;
    if (isNaN(cookies)) {
        console.log('The totalCookies entry is not numerical');
        // etc...
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know that and that fixed all my problems!

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because when you declare a variable to be an object, you're creating a *reference* to the object, not a duplicate of it. You can use the **get** & **set** methods of `localStorage`, as mentioned by War10ck in the comments above:

Get: `localStorage.getItem('totalCookies')`
Set: `localStorage.setItem('totalCookies', 'some value')`
Remove: `localStorage.removeItem('totalCookies')`

But in general, you need to find a way to clone an object to prevent subsequent tampering with the original. Here's a quick way:

```
var cloneOfA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(a));
```

You can see a larger discussion about this here:
[How do I correctly clone a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: What happens is there is a timer event, that adds the value of Autoclick to the totalCookies. But when I use: getItem, or setItem every second it adds the value of the autoclick like so: var autoclick = 0; Total Cookies: 120, Next Second: Total Cookies: 1200, Next second Total Cookies: 12000. Why does it do that?

Comment: It looks like you might be adding strings to strings instead of integers to integers. You'll need to use `parseInt()` to make sure javascript knows to treat it as an integer. Try:
`var totalCookies = 0;`
`totalCookies = totalCookies + parseInt(newCookie)`

Comment: Or see trincot's smarter answer above!